# Converting one to many mapping dictionary to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
d={1:(array[2,3]), 2:(array[8,4,5]), 3:(array[6,7,8,9])}
```

As depicted, here the values for each key are variable length arrays.

Now I want to convert it to DataFrame. So the output looks like:

```
A   B
1   2
1   3
2   8
2   4
2   5
3   6
3   7
3   8
3   9
```

I used pd.Dataframe(d), but it does not handle one to many mapping.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pd.DataFrame(
    [[k, v] for k, a in d.items() for v in a.tolist()],
    columns=['A', 'B']
)

   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  3
2  2  8
3  2  4
4  2  5
5  3  6
6  3  7
7  3  8
8  3  9
```

---

**Setup**

```
d = {1: np.array([2,3]), 2: np.array([8,4,5]), 3: np.array([6,7,8,9])}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html) constructor with [`str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) for lenghts of `lists` (`array`s was converted to `lists`).

Then create new [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) with [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html),  [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) and [`Index.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.values.html):

```
d = {1:np.array([2,3]), 2:np.array([8,4,5]), 3:np.array([6,7,8,9])}
print (d)

a = pd.Series(d)
l = a.str.len()
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.repeat(a.index.values, l), 'B': np.concatenate(a.values)})
print (df)
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  3
2  2  8
3  2  4
4  2  5
5  3  6
6  3  7
7  3  8
8  3  9
```

Comment: Very nice answer. But when I am execute this using same example, the last df constructor statement gives me following error "repeat takes 2 argument, 3 given)

Comment: I am using above example only. It works fine till l=a.str.len(). But as stated, it gives me the error in last statement.

Comment: No df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.repeat(a.index, l), 'B': np.concatenate(a.values)}) returns an error as :TypeError: repeat() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Comment: Yes this works. Thank you!!. But what was the problem in previous one?

Comment: I dont know, for me works both versions. I use last version of pandas (0.20.1)  and python 3, maybe there is problem.

Comment: I am using python 2.7...that may be the cause...anyway the second one executes.....

Answer (score 2):

Here's my version:

```
(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').rename_axis('A')
                                          .stack()
                                          .reset_index(name='B')
                                          .drop('level_1', axis=1)
                                          .astype('int'))
Out[63]: 
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  3
2  2  8
3  2  4
4  2  5
5  3  6
6  3  7
7  3  8
8  3  9
```